# Makes sense build a library for an entire feature?

Tags: angularjs

We have a small complete application where it will be used by another applications. It is composed by Routes, Services, Utils and etc. Was asked to transform this application into a component npm. Makes sense build a npm module of entire project to share it?  What alternatives could I suggest?

Comment: I think an NPM package makes sense. So long as it's more or less just a copy of the shared code. The only other thing I can think of is having a shared repository that all the different teams and devs can pull from. Regardless though, I'd keep an emphasis on them being able to dig into the guts of the 'library' because eventually somebody IS going to want to customize it or change it to suit their style and needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip out all the shared and commonly used functions and externalize them to be imported into the view.

If you are expected to do the same business logic over and over again, you can move it into the library as well, but I wouldn't advise just sticking the entire application inside an node module and installing that.

If you want to do it right, look up [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and design your library to accept functions and parameters to make things as modular and generic as possible.

What you don't want to have happen is every time you want to add a feature to a view or change something, you have to rebuild and redeploy the module just to import it back, so try and design the library to the lowest common denominator.

The angular modules should have some level of portability, so you could find features that are complete enough and find a way to have some sort of configuration object to pass in.

Comment: I think it's generally inadvisable to have any business logic implemented in a library since it's subject to immense change more often than not. But that's a good point about rebuilding and redeploying, especially if there are a lot of applications that are dependant on it, the process for getting everyone up to date could be a pain (*points at tremendous tech debt in literally every piece of software*).